# Maven Error Resolving version for plugin

Tags: java, maven, kurento

I am trying to run a kurento-java client hello world example as given in this link 
http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-helloworld.html

I am providing a kurento media server url while compiling the code as

> mvn compile exec:java -Dkms.url=ws://kms_host:kms_port/kurento

I keep getting error as:

Error resolving version for plugin '.url=ws://kms_host:kms_port' from the repositories

Answer (score 16):

Are you using PowerShell ?

PowerShell does not recognize line parameter as follow

```
-Dname.of.myparameter=somting
```

Use "old" windows command prompt instead.

Comment: yeah, that works... unbelievable :)

Answer (score 3):

Change to regular windows command prompt

Answer (score 1):

This error will be thrown if you have a space before the dot in `-Dkms.url`. Please make sure to run the command exactly as in the documentation you are referring to.

Comment: There is no space

Comment: Clearly the command-line interpreter recognized .url=ws://kms_host:kms_port as a separate token. Copy the entire string into a simple text editor (not Word) to see if there are any invisible characters. No line breaks either.